# Can variables be passed as argumets to webpack loaders?

Tags: javascript, webpack, coffeescript

I've just written a second webpack loader. This time I looked into accepting arguments via the query params passed to `require`. Now my public API looks like this (coffeescript):

```
asset_url = require "../assets/eyes.gif?resize=150x150&to_webm=true"
```

that `require` call is passed the original asset path plus some parameters. As the params instruct, it resizes it and converts it to webm, returning the new path.

The problem is that Webpack need static `requires`. i.e. if I change it to the following (again, coffeescript):

```
params = "resize=150x150&to_webm=true"
asset_url = require "../assets/eyes.gif?#{params}"
```

Then webpack says `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../assets"` even though it works perfectly fine when I don't use a variable.

So, is my Webpack loader limited to this way of passing arguments? Although Webpack's functionality is very advanced, this one aspect seems very primitive.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack statically parses your compiled CoffeeScript code and looks for `require` calls. your compiled coffee code will look like this:

```
asset_url = require("../assets/eyes.gif?" + params)
```

Generally Webpack creates a context when it sees a parameter in `require calls` [as described here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#require-with-expression) but as you can see it has no way of guessing your loader arguments at bundling time so it throws an error.

Comment: The way I'm reading this is that it's only possible when the variable refers to the filename of something that's already on the system. However, the params here are not part of the path, so I don't see how the context module would work.

Comment: @maxple exactly. What I'm saying is due to static nature of the webpack require you simply cannot do this